# Usage of "for" in "Scaramucci’s official start date was set for Aug. 15"

Tags: prepositions, difference

> Scaramucci’s official start date was set **for** Aug. 15

I doubt the usage of "for" in this sentence. Can we use to/at/on here? Any difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's correct.

As I see it, using *to* has a similar meaning, but it is unidiomatic. You would use *to* when setting a clock or other time-keeping device

> I set my digital watch to August 15.

*At*  suggests (to me) that the date on which the start date was set was August 15, but it's unidiomatic.

*On* implies that the date on which the start date was set was August 15. It does not tell us the official start date.
*Example. Scaramucci’s official start date was set **on** August 15*.

> Aug. 15: We hired Scaramucci on August 15. We told him, "Your official start date is August 20."
>   Aug. 20: Scaramucci officially starts.

For comparison, *for* tells us the official start date, but not when it was actually set.
*Example. Scaramucci’s official start date was set **for** August 15*.

> July 21: We hired Scaramucci on July 21. We told him, "Your official start date is August 15."
>   Aug. 15:  Scaramucci officially starts.

Notice that this example is implied by *Scaramucci’s official start date was set **on** July 21 **for** August 15*.